# Show data only by userId in token

Tags: authentication, sails.js, token, endpoint

I googled :) But I can't find solution how to protect Endpoints properly, problems are when I signed user I've got token and my userId is 1 and then I can make GET and POST requests, but if I use route example:  blablabla.com/users/1 I can see all data and blablabla.com/users/2 as well I can see all data. How to restrict and show data only for id which one is signed but for rest id make forbidden request

Thanks for your reply

Comment: you can enrypt and decrypt id when pass in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use policies to achieve this.
First, you have to create a custom policy.

create a file `api/policies/isAuthorised.js`

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  let token;
  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    const parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parts.length === 2) {
      const scheme = parts[0];
      const credentials = parts[1];
      if (/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
        token = credentials;
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]'
      });
    }
  } else if (req.param('token')) {
    token = req.param('token');

    delete req.query.token;
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'No authorization header was found'
    });
  }
  // replace it with you own token verfication mechanism
  sails.helpers.jwt.verify(token, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Invalid Token!'
      });
    }
    req.token = token;
    User.findOne({
      id: decoded.userid
    }).then((user) => {
      req.currentUser = user;
      next();
    });
  });

};
```

This policy will make sure that the user is accessing with a valid token.
You need another policy to restrict to own documents only.
Create another one in file `api/policies/isOwner.js`

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    switch (req.options.model) {
      case 'user': {
        User.findOne({
          id: req.param('id')
        }).then(
          (user) => {
            if (!user) {
              return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Invalid request'
              });
            }
            if ( user.id === req.currentUser.id) {
              next();
            }
            else {
              return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Invalid request'
              });
            }
          }
        );
        break;
      }
      default: {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: 'Invalid request'
        });
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Bad Request'
    });
  }
};
```

Now apply both these policies to you controller

```
config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {

  '*': false,
  UserController: {
    '*': false, //this will prevent accessing any other api such as delelt update etc.
    'findOne': ['isAuthorised', 'isOwner'],
  },
};
```